# Can the compiler I made still be called a compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, terminology

The compiler I'm making works by generating C code which later on will be compiled again to an executable file by another compiler (default is tcc).

Is this still a compiler?

Comment: I would call this a "transpiler": a source-to-source translator.

Comment: @marco-a so, haxe is transpiler too?

Comment: yes it could be called a compiler.

Answer (score 5):

Well it can be called a compiler.
A compiler is a program that translates computer code written in one programming language (the source language) into another language (the target language). So your program could be classified as a compiler.